# Assignment means point to address in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am implementing a Hierarchy clustering algorithm(with similarity) using python 3.6, the following doing is basically build new empty graph ,and  keep connecting the the group(represent by list here ) with largest similarity on original recursively

the code in position 1 of code ,I want to return the best partition, however the function return is exactly the same as `comminity_list`,it looks like `best_partition = comminity_list.` make `best_partition` point to the address of 'comminity_list' how come it happens, what I got wrong here? how should I fix that ?

```
def pearson_clustering(G):

    H = nx.create_empty_copy(G). # build a empty copy of G(no vetices)
    best = 0    #for current modularity 
    current =0  #for best modualarty
    A = nx.adj_matrix(G).  #get adjacent matrix  
    org_deg =deg_dict(A, G.nodes()) # degree of G
    org_E = G.number_of_edges(). # number of edges of G
    comminity_list = intial_commnity_list(G) # function return a list of lists here
    best_partition = None
    p_table =pearson_table(G)  #pearson_table return a dictionary of each pair Pearson correlation 
    l = len(comminity_list)  

    while True:
        if(l == 2): break 
        current = modualratiry(H,org_deg,org_E) #find current modularity
        l = len(comminity_list)
        p_build_cluster(p_table,H,G,comminity_list)  #building clustering on H    
        if(best < current):
             best_partition = comminity_list. #postion1
             best = current            #find the clustering with largest modularity    

    return best_partition #postion2
```

Comment: Assignment doesn't implicitly copy in Python. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it looks like best_partition = comminity_list. make best_partition point to the address of 'comminity_list' how come it happens, what I got wrong here? how should I fix that ?

That is just python's implicit assignment behaviour. When you do "best_partition = comminity_list" you just assign comminity_list to the same address as best_partition.

If you want to explicitly copy the list you can use this (which replaces the list best_partition with the comminity_list):

```
best_partition[:] = comminity_list
```

or the [copy function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html). If comminity_list has sublists you will need the deepcopy function instead, from the same module (otherwise you will get a copy of the original list, but the sublists will still be just address references).

```
best_partition = comminity_list.copy
```